# Axios giving 401 unauthorised with react

Tags: reactjs, axios, strapi

[My code for fetching data from strapi server through my Homepage]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKTIU.png)
`const Home=()=>{useEffect(()=>{getCategories()},[]); const getCategories=()=>{fetchDataFromAPI("/api/categories").then(res => console.log(res))};`

Comment: Please answer my question I`m a newbie in development and spent almost 3 hours to fix this issue

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please add authorization header as headers:{authorization:'Bearer xxxxx--token--xxxx'}

Comment: Please go through [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) then edit your question.

Comment: It should be `Bearer`, not `bearer`

Answer (score -1):

Having a little more context will help.  Based on the image that you provided it seems that your code is correct.

I am assuming you have the correct token in the `.env` file.  If it is correct, than you should check in the Strapi admin that you gave the correct api permissions when creating a token.

My app does not have `categories`, I have `events` so that is what you are going to see in the example bellow.

In Strapi Go To **Settings** => **API Tokens**
[image]

If you don't have a token, you will have to create one. If you do have one than you can regenerate.  But you must make sure that you give the correct permissions.

I will use my `events` collection type as an example.

[image]

Fill in all the required information and click save.

[image]

Copy the token to your clipboard and paste it in your .env file in your application.

Also, to check if the issue is in your react code or strapi app, you can first test it using **Postman** or **Insomnia**

I will use insomnia to call my endpoint with my auth token. Again in my example I have events not categories.

Notice when making an authorized request using bearer token I am able to return my data.

[image]

Now that I know my Strapi app is working accordingly, I can not test this in my react application.

Hope this helps.